# azure acive directory validation error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Im having an issue with a web app in azure.  I use active directory to control access which works well, but one of my users gets this error message when they login in

idx10214 audience validation failed did not match validationparameters.validaudience or validationparameters null

does anyone know what this means ? Is there a workaround ?

heres how I setup openid to authorize users, how would i include the audience settings here ?  What should the audience value be ?

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = AuthorityCHP,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = loURL,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential credential = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext authContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(AuthorityCHP, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                        var newuri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));
                        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, newuri, credential, graphResourceId);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Ive added some additional code in the hope it might work, but after i deployed it, i got the user affecetd to try logging in again and its still the same.  Im not consuming a webapi its just a straightforwrsd webapp with a standard login page, Im really stumped, why is it only one particular user thats affecetd by this ?  Can anynoe help ?

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidAudience = clientId
            },
            Tenant = tenantId,
            AuthenticationType = "OAuth2Bearer"
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

That's mean you were calling the API using the incorrect token. When we call a web API which protected by Azure AD, it will verify the signature of the token and claims in the token.

The `audience` is used to which resource the token is able to access. We should acquire the token based on the resource. For example, if we protect the web API with code below, we should use the **audience** config in the below to acquire the token.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
            Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
        });

    //app.UsePasswordAuthentication();
}
```

## update

```
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    // In a real application you would use IssuerValidator for additional checks, like making sure the user's organization has signed up for your app.
    //     IssuerValidator = (issuer, token, tvp) =>
    //     {
    //        //if(MyCustomTenantValidation(issuer)) 
    //        return issuer;
    //        //else
    //        //    throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("Invalid issuer");
    //    },
},
```

Comment: What's the value of `graphResourceId`? Which API you were request and how it was protected?

Comment: looks like there was an error reading this from the key, but the code still executed even though there was no value for the graphResourceId, could this be the cause ?

Comment: No matter what's value, if you were accessing the web API the audience should match the resource you were acquire the token. The two value doesn't match is the root cause for this issue! Please share the how you protecting the web API if it is also developed by you or share more detail info you were developing!

Comment: i dont understand what you mean 'protecting the web api' im developing a web app

Comment: Which line of code cause the audience validation failed exception?

Comment: and the code I supplied is how im authenticating users

Comment: This is happening in my qa enviroment for one particular user, I cant duplicate error in my dev environment

Comment: the qa environment is hosted in azure

Comment: The code you sharing will not cause this issue. As I mentioned in the post, the issue only occurred when the web API trying to verifying the token. Without the further detailed info, it is hard to give the helpful suggestion.

Comment: what web api ? i dont understand what you mean

Comment: the code I posted is called when my app starts up, thats the only place its used

Comment: I tried including your code but I get this error  'IAppBuilder does not contain a definition for UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication

Comment: The code in the post is used for the web API side to demo verify the token. This piece of code shouldn't used in the client-side(client-resource mode).

Comment: @proteus Sorry for the confusion. I also got this issue when I wrote a Asp.Net core 2.0 integrate with V2.0 endpoint. Please check whether your QA environment integrate with Azure AD V2.0. If yes you need to verify the issuer yourself, please refer the update in the post. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: sorted it eventually, the users browser had somehow remembered an older version of the cookie even after I asked them to clear the browser history and data.  Had to uninstall the browser and then reinstall and it worked

Comment: Glad to hear the issue was fixed. However it sounds strange, not able to understand why this issue is relative to the browser and cookie.

Comment: only one particular user was experiencing this issue, I am developing at the moment and I have been removing the apps from azure and recreating them so they get different client id's that's the only reason I can think of